# I have a Spanish registered car in Spain. However I still have an old style British driving license do I need to get an International one?

Tags: driving, driving-licenses

I have a Spanish registered car in Spain. However I still have an old style British driving license do I need to get an International one when I am driving there?

Comment: Joseph do you live in Spain or do you live elsewhere and only visit at times?

Comment: Rolled back as the question was changed too much. The question is about the driving license, not about whether OP can have a car or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all clear what is meant by a `old style British driving license`.

This answer *assumes* an EU style is meant. Any of the older versions (like the Red Book style) would probably not be accepted.

It is also not clear if you will be **visiting** or if you are a Spanish **resident**.

Important is only if, based on your *status*, you are allowed to drive (and **not** where the car is registered).

---

If you are a **UK resident** (i.e. visiting Spain):

- you will **not** need an **international driving permit (IDP)**

If you are a Spanish **resident**

- you will be required to **exchange** your UK licence

You should make this application **during** 2020 to avoid having to take Spanish drivers test.

This can be done electronicly (see [Step 1 and 2 in 'Driving in Spain'](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-spain#driving-in-spain)). The process must be completed by the end of June 2021.

---

**Sources**:

- [Driving abroad: Check if you need an international driving permit (IDP) - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/driving-abroad/international-driving-permit)

  - **Spain**: You do not need an IDP to drive here.
- [Driving in the EU from 1 January 2021: UK licence holders living in the EU - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/driving-in-the-eu-from-1-january-2021-uk-licence-holders-living-in-the-eu)

  - [Living in Spain - Driving in Spain - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-spain#driving-in-spain)